# WCF service private fields

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I don't have much experience in WCF and need clarification for an issue.

Are WCF private fields stored during a session - when a client app creates a connection to WCF and calls methods from the service? Is the state of these fields independent for various clients? Is it a good idea to store large data in them and use it for paging?

Comment: have a look at http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=wcf+#/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A266239%2Ck%3Awcf&page=2&keywords=wcf&ie=UTF8&qid=1310546992  any good WCF book will cover this sort of thing, you need to **understand** a lot more then what a single stackover answer will give you

Comment: tell it to my boss and deadline

Comment: if you are unwilling to spend the time and effert to learn, you should not expect anyone else to write the software for you "free of charge!"  Your boss is your problem and is not a reason to spam the internet with "please help me becouse I am not willing to help myself" posts.

Comment: @Ian, he's not expecting you to do that - he's asking a specific question along the lines of "should I do X?" on a site that's designed for that kind of thing.  Marc Gravell has the right idea.

Comment: I'm sorry if you felt offended. That wasn't my intention. Actual situation was that my boss knew that I don't know wcf and still gave this project to me. I'm willing to spend time and effort to learn, I only don't have time and all I want is clarificaion if can I use private service fields for cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't keep *anything* in the WCF service implementation instance, but then I also don't enable "session" - simply, I want any client to be able to connect to any server, without the overheads of session tracking, sticky load balancing, etc.

If you want session, I'd *personally* do it outside of WCF, but in your case it sounds like you are really looking for something closer to a cache anyway. Either way, there are plenty of ways of implementing that preserve the (desirable to me, at least) stateless query metaphor. Sure, the *data* might still be around for re-use, but I don't need a session for that.